# Cinematic Sound Design Project

Tags: portfolio

Hey Guys

Been working on re-creating some sound design to an animation for practise and feel like I am at a good point to get some feedback from people.  If you get a chance, its just over 1 minute long, have a watch/listen and let me know what you think.

The deflecting arrow scene I feel needs work and is the weakest point.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5CodXfC7iK4

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds very basic and linear, but a great start.

About 20seconds in the sound fails to create an impact. Make them bows sound big! the flames sound huge, get more leathery sounds in there for where the hand grips the bow, or riders grip reins etc. Layer up the sound of the horses and riders and use perspective, for example when you see the white horse fly over you.

There is no sense of the amount of arrows coming towards the white rider and deflecting the arrows is indeed weak. I think it needs the sound of wood hitting wood and the spinning of the spear would help... I think the high pitch whoooses would disappear now too.

These spring to mind but probably better examples out there: 
http://youtu.be/qdDdHMwhU2s?t=2m8s
http://youtu.be/L6EknwERf3o?t=1m28s

Anyway good luck, think it will sound amazing once you add a bit more to it :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi there

Here's my two cents worth.

The sound effect tracks for this probably totaled to no more than 4 tracks. Try add more tracks of sound effects to reduce holes and dips. You don't always necessary need to put the obvious sounds down. Create an atmosphere . Make use of "off screen effects"
Pick a point of view for the viewer, Ie are you on the horse attacking or are you being attacked. Both have different feels. Pick one then try understand what that person would be feeling .

Comment: good comment! :) second that!

Answer (score 0):

Very cool! I like what you have there so far. I think the next step is to add some more detail and character to the sounds. To add to what has already been mentioned:

- The whizzes of the arrows sound a lot like passing bullet, rather than a larges shaft of wood with a feather that are on fire.
- The moment when the female rider's horse erupts through the flame can be much larger and more intimidating.
- I think you can get even more blood-and-guts from the moment at the end when the female warrior attacks
- When she attacks, give every detail a sound

  - Her spear digging into the ground when she leaps
  - The creak of armor as she leaves the horse
  - The whoosh as her body does a full flip in the air
  - The flutter of her cape as it billows in the fast wind
    ... all of these details will make the moment much more significant and menacing
- The body falls of the dead warriors lack in low frequency content and a sense of momentum
- I very much like the effect of the dead warriors' horses continuing off even after their riders have fallen. The moment afterward, however, is very sudden and lacks a build. It doesn't have to be long (even less than a second), but I would like to hear some sound or sounds as she turns her head, building up to the cut that shows the horned warrior behind her.

Cheers,

~Matt